# How to update Boolean field in database through DataGridView by button click in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The DataGridView displays values from my database table, Consider in this table I have 8 fields and I want to update only 2 particular fields through DataGridView. Out of this 2 fields, one field is of Boolean type - thus it appears as checked box in DataGridView when the value in database table is "1". So when I un-check, it should update database table with value "0" and 2nd field is a int type.

Once I make changes in these two particular fields(cells) in DataGridView, I should be able to update database table through a BUTTON click (windows Form C#).

Can anyone help me on handling this coding part or on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

In your button click handler, you'll want to do something like this:

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["checkColumnName"].ToString())
                {
                    // do checked thing
                }
                else
                {
                    // do unchecked thing
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve in this way. Hope this help.
If you have a datagridview with Boolean/Bit field and want to update the field in database based on the checked/Unchecked event you do in the datagridview can write this piece of code(in Update Button click event, to update multiple records of the Boolean field)

```
try
{ 
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) //looping through each records in datagridview
 { 
   //Update query
   strQuery = @"Update TableA Set ActiveInactive = @ActiveInactive --Boolean field
                Where Id = @Id ";

   cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, // provide sql connection string here));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", row.Cells["SystemIdentifier"].Value); //reading Id of a particular record
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActiveInactive", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["ActiveInactive"].Value) ? 1 : 0);
   //reading Boolean field of a particular record
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
   MessageBox.Show("The records in the table has been updated.", "Information");

}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString(), "Error");
}
```

Note: I had declared required variables in the form load and had created a class for sql connection string which is called in whenever required.